# NoMethodError in SettingsController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_setting, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  authorize_resource class: false

  def edit
  end

  def index
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if Setting.first.update!(setting_params)
        format.html { redirect_to settings_path, notice: "Settings Successfully Updated" }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: settings_path }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: Settings.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_setting
     @setting = Setting.first(params[:id])
    end

    def setting_params
      params.require(:setting).permit(:component_kinds, :client_kinds, :folder_kinds)
    end
end
```

Here's more error information - I got the following error while update the values:

```
`NoMethodError (undefined method update!' for nil:NilClass): app/controllers/settings_controller.rb:13:in block in update' app/controllers/settings_controller.rb:12:in `update'
```

Comment: please give us full trace

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is good you posted us some code, but an explanation of what the problem is and what you want help with would enable us to assist you. Use the [edit] button to add some text that explains your question for us.

Answer (score 1):

This is being caused because there are no settings in the database. This results in `Setting.first` being nil, which in turn results in your error message of *undefined method update! for nil:NilClass* when you try to call update! on it.

You may consider switching to [the first! method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first-21), which will raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error if no record is found. This will provide you with a way to troubleshoot in development, and a nice 404 in production.

Another way to fix it might be to [check for existence](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class) before trying to update, like so:

`if Setting.exist? && Setting.first.update!(setting_params)`

Comment: I have the settings in the database.  create_table "settings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "settable_type"
    t.integer  "settable_id"
    t.hstore   "settables"
    t.integer  "created_by"
    t.integer  "updated_by"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end

Comment: I doubt it. Try running `Setting.first` in the console. I bet it is nil. Or, adjust the method like I recommended, and you will get a record not found error.

Comment: Entries in the settings table, not the table itself. First retrieves the first entry.

Comment: Also, this is not going to work like you expect, even after you fix that, due to things like `Settings.errors`... This advice will only fix the specific error referenced, not the entire controller.

Comment: You are calling Setting.first twice, due to the `set_setting` method.